# Error in Angular 4.x Karma test "No Provider for FocusTrapFactory"

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I have a small Angular v4.x using Angluar Material 2.x
It has a modal (using MdDialog) login component - and pretty much nothing else.
All my tests are failing with:

> Failed: No provider for FocusTrapFactory! at injectionError
>   (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?31c6eb17e2414560f8e07e35e9c56bebb408ba58:2074:86)
>   [angular]
>       at noProviderError (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?31c6eb17e2414560f8e07e35e9c56bebb408ba58:2112:12)
>   [angular] ...

my login.component.spec.ts is

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MdDialog, MdDialogContainer, MdInputContainer, OVERLAY_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/material';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../shared/servicesIndex';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

describe('LoginComponent', () => {
    let component: LoginComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
            set: {
                entryComponents: [MdDialogContainer]
            }
        });
        TestBed.configureTestingModule(
            {
            imports: [
                FormsModule,
                RouterTestingModule,
                HttpModule,
                NoopAnimationsModule

            ],
            declarations: [
                LoginComponent,
                MdInputContainer,
                MdDialogContainer
            ],
            providers: [
                MdDialog,
                OVERLAY_PROVIDERS,
                AuthenticationService
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents();

    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Logic tells me to import FocusTrapFactory and add it to my list of providers - but I can't find it to import it!

I'm at a loss. My Google-fu is fu.

Answer (score 1):

Just needed to add `import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';` then add `MaterialModule` to the `imports` array in my **app.component.spec.ts**.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the right packages for the material components. Unfortunately `MaterialModule` is marked depricated in the latest release.

The best way to replace this is to make your own Module that imports (and exports) only the modules that are actually used in your application.

I managed to fix this issue by creating this class:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MdMenuModule, MdIconModule, MdRippleModule, MdToolbarModule, MdSidenavModule, MdButtonModule } from '@angular/material'
// Add animations
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

const MATERIAL_MODULES = [
    MdMenuModule,
    MdIconModule,
    MdRippleModule,
    MdToolbarModule,
    MdSidenavModule,
    MdButtonModule, 
    BrowserAnimationsModule
];

@NgModule({
  imports: MATERIAL_MODULES,
  exports: MATERIAL_MODULES
})
export class AngularMaterialModule { }
```

This module should be included in your own `app.module`

Good luck!